# How to confirm multiple processes shares mapping area,created using mmap with MAP_SHARED flag

Tags: c, linux, memory

I have created two independent processes process1 and process2,which does mapping(using mmap with MAP_SHARED flag) to same file(or)object,in such a case the mapped area should be shared b/w processes. When i printed the return value of mmap system call of two processes the address printed was different,i believe the printed address is virtual address so its different but physical address might be same. Please correct me if iam wrong.

After reading through threads in stack overflow i came to know that we cannot convert physical to virtual address from user space. So is there any other way i could confirm the mapped area is shared b/w process?.

Comment: You are correct about how two different virtual addresses can map to the same physical address (especially since they're different process spaces). As far as confirming that it's shared, you may be able to look in `/proc/<pid>/maps`, or just try to use the shared memory (with `MAP_SHARED`, it should work).

Answer (score 0):

Just write some magic numbers in there.  If the second process sees the magic numbers, well, you're looking at the same memory.

Comment: HI john i'm not getting you,could you please explain little elaborate.

Comment: You say you want to confirm that two programs are actually sharing a piece of memory.  So just have one of them write some known text to the memory, such as its PID or a special string like "I'm the captain now."  Then have the other program read and see if the text is in there.

Comment: Ya John,i understood that,but what i need is,i have to read from RAM from user space,is there any system call to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for, then.  Perhaps you can tell us what actual problem you're trying to solve?